# How to pull a value out of an element in a nested XML document in Python?

Tags: python, xml

I'm asking an API to look up part numbers I get from a user with a barcode scanner. The API returns a much longer document than the below code block, but I trimmed a bunch of unnecessary empty elements, but the structure of the document is still the same. I need to put each part number in a dictionary where the value is the text inside of the `<mfgr>` element. With each run of my program, I generate a list of part numbers and have a loop that asks the API about each item in my list and each returns a huge document as expected. I'm a bit stuck on trying to parse the XML and get only the text inside of `<mfgr>` element, then save it to a dictionary with the part number that it belongs to. I'll put my loop that goes through my list below the XML document

```
<ArrayOfitem xmlns="WhereDataComesFrom.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <item>
        <associateditem_swap/>
        <bulk>false</bulk>
        <category>Memory</category>
        <clei>false</clei>
        <createddate>5/11/2021 7:34:58 PM</createddate>
        <description>sample description</description>
        <heci/>
        <imageurl/>
        <item_swap/>
        <itemid>1640</itemid>
        <itemnumber>**sample part number**</itemnumber>
        <listprice>0.0000</listprice>
        <manufactureritem/>
        <maxavailable>66</maxavailable>
        <mfgr>**sample manufacturer**</mfgr>
        <minreorderqty>0</minreorderqty>
        <noninventory>false</noninventory>
        <primarylocation/>
        <reorderpoint>0</reorderpoint>
        <rep>AP</rep>
        <type>Memory                                  </type>
        <updateddate>2/4/2022 2:22:51 PM</updateddate>
        <warehouse>MAIN</warehouse>
    </item>
</ArrayOfitem>
```

Below is my Python code that loops through the part number list and asks the API to look up each part number.

```
import http.client
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
raw_xml = None
pn_list=["samplepart1","samplepart2"]
api_key= **redacted lol**

def getMFGR():
    global raw_xml
    for part_number in pn_list:
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.website.com")
        payload = ''
        headers = {
        'session-token': 'api_key',
        'Cookie': 'firstpartofmycookie; secondpartofmycookie'
        }
        conn.request("GET", "/webapi.svc/MI/XML/GetItemsByItemNumber?ItemNumber="+part_number, payload, headers)
        res = conn.getresponse()
        data = res.read()
        raw_xml = data.decode("utf-8")
        print(raw_xml)
        print()

getMFGR()
```

Here is some code I tried while trying to get the mfgr. It will go inside the `getMFGR()` method inside the for loop so that it saves the manufacturer to a variable with each loop. Once the code works I want to have the dictionary look like this: `{"samplepart1": "manufacturer1", "samplepart2": "manufacturer2"}`.

```
root = etree.fromstring(raw_xml)
my_ns = {'root': 'WhereDataComesFrom.com'}

mfgr = root.findall('root:mfgr',my_ns)[0].text
```

The code above gives me a list index out of range error when I run it. I don't think it's searching past the namespaces node but I'm not sure how to tell it to search further.

Answer (score 1):

This is where an interactive session becomes very useful. Drop your XML data into a file (say, `data.xml`), and then start up a Python REPL:

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree
>>> with open('data.xml') as fd:
...     raw_xml=fd.read()
...
>>> root = etree.fromstring(raw_xml)
>>> my_ns = {'root': 'WhereDataComesFrom.com'}
```

Let's first look at your existing xpath expression:

```
>>> root.findall('root:mfgr',my_ns)
[]
```

That returns an empty list, which is why you're getting an "index out of range" error. You're getting an empty list because there is no `mfgr` element at the top level of the document; it's contained in an `<item>` element. So this will work:

```
>>> root.findall('root:item/root:mfgr',my_ns)
[<Element '{WhereDataComesFrom.com}mfgr' at 0x7fa5a45e2b60>]
```

To actually get the contents of that element:

```
>>> [x.text for x in root.findall('root:item/root:mfgr',my_ns)]
['**sample manufacturer**']
```

Hopefully that's enough to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use pandas for this structure of XML:

```
import pandas as pd

# Read XML row into DataFrame
ns = {"xmlns":"WhereDataComesFrom.com", "xmlns:i":"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"}
df = pd.read_xml("parNo_plant.xml", xpath=".//xmlns:item", namespaces=ns)

# Print only columns of interesst
df_of_interest = df[['itemnumber', 'mfgr']]
print(df_of_interest,'\n')

#Print the dictionary from DataFrame
print(df_of_interest.to_dict(orient='records'))

# If I understood right, you search this layout:
dictionary = dict(zip(df.itemnumber, df.mfgr))
print(dictionary)
```

Result (Pandas dataframe or dictionary):

```
               itemnumber                     mfgr
0  **sample part number**  **sample manufacturer** 

[{'itemnumber': '**sample part number**', 'mfgr': '**sample manufacturer**'}]

{'**sample part number**': '**sample manufacturer**'}
```